# How to change the default look of radio button, not functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, radio-button

On a form I've two radio button **Yes** and **No**. I want to change the default look of radio buttons

[image][image]

to like this.

[image]

**Edit:** I would like to change the `radio` buttons into `<a>` anchor when JavaScript is enabled if it's not easy to change the look of default radio  via css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way?  Set the images as labels with the `for` attribute pointing to the radio buttons.  Then set the radio buttons to `display:none;`

```
<input type="radio" name="radio[1]" /><label for="radio[1]"><img src="/yes.png"></label>
<input type="radio" name="radio[2]" /><label for="radio[2]"><img src="/no.png"></label>
```

p.s. This uses built in HTML functionality that works everywhere and doesn't require javascript.  Use some CSS meta selectors (:hover etc...) to add animation.

UPDATE:

Just looping back after a long time and realised this could do with a little more explanation for beginners.  When the `for` attribute is set on a label, clicking the label is functionally the same as clicking the element it's `for` attribute points to.  For completeness, the `for` attribute should be set to the `id` of the form element.

Comment: Sorry for the unproductive comment, I was trying to find out myself at the time. The button does not seem to be updated if the button is conventionally hidden/not displayed (to find that out one would need a stylesheet of the sort `input[type=radio] + label { color:red ;}` or some JS (your version does not give any visual feedback yet). I found out that the stylesheet for the label only gets re-evaluated when you zoom and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzVSB/3/) shows that via JS you can't detect a checked button either. Hiding it nonconventionally à la `opacity: 0` worked.

Comment: @Ruben interesting.  I wasn't trying to provide any way to visually indicate which radio button is selected. I was only providing a way to hide the radio buttons but have them selected when some UI element is clicked without using javascript.  If you write up an answer on how to make it work in mobile chrome, I'll certainly give you a +1

Comment: @Ruben Also, have you tried doing something in the css like `input[type=radio]:checked + label { color:red; }`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to coerce the images to work with the `<radio>` tag, I would just put the images where you want them, bind the various behaviors to them using jQuery, and have them modify hidden input fields. I think it will be much easier that way.